# Preview/rendering of the animation stops at a certain point

Tags: rendering, animation, timeline

I have the start frame set to 1, and end 400, but for some reason the yellow strip at the animation timeline stops at 250.
[image: half way done?]

Comment: Maybe a screen grab would help... The yellow strip in dope sheet? If so, yellow diamonds connected by a yellow line indicate frames overwhich the keyframed value does not change.... Like two keyframes for location over which there is no change in location... They would be connected by a yellow line.

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to upload that.

Comment: Maybe you have some physics or other cached actions? Solid body or something? Looks like the cache is partially rendered? See https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?384272-What-is-the-yellow-line-in-the-timeline-and-how-to-expand-it  or perhaps there is something better here on stackexchange...

Comment: And the timeline section here might help: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/timeline.html

Comment: The first link really helped! Thanks a bunch, Rcgauer!